# Как считывать данные из access в python

Tags: python, ms-access

Помогите пожалуйста, у меня есть бд Access там есть таблица и у нее названия на кириллице("ТАБЛИЦА ОДИН")
и при при чтения данных с помощью Python у меня появляется ошибка:

> '42S02', '[42S02] [Microsoft][Драйвер ODBC Microsoft Access] Ядру СУБД Microsoft Access не удается найти входную таблицу или запрос "ТАБЛИЦА". Убедитесь, что объект существует, а его имя указано правильно. (-1305) (SQLExecDirectW)')

```
con_string = r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; ' \
             r'DBQ=Database.accdb;'
conn = pyodbc.connect(con_string)

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from ТАБЛИЦА ОДИН')

for row in cur.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

P.S. Менять название таблицы нельзя, должна оставаться название на кириллице и пробелом.

Подскажите как считать данные с этой таблицы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cnxm = pyodbc.connect(driver=access_driver, dbq=filepath, autocommit=True)
crsr = cnxm.cursor()
table_list = list(crsr.tables())
table_name = f'([ТАБЛИЦА ОДИН])'
qwerty = 'SELECT * FROM {}'.format(table_name)

crsr.execute(qwerty)
```

получилось решить вопрос таким решением